# Wireless connection to DSL Modem-Router restarts on heavy usage

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking

The title says it all. When I download alot of stuff the wireless connection will close. After 10-20 secs it will reconnect.

What could be causing this? What is more likely to be the cause, my wireless adapter or the router?

Comment: Are you sure its the router/modem? Or is it a single computer.

Comment: There are some adsl2 modems that will shut down when too many tcp connections are made.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this is happening for just one machine, or whether it is affecting all the devices on your network.

If it's just affecting a single machine I'd lean towards adapter. A larger outage may be indicative of a more central problem with the router.

In the past I've had strange behaviour like this when my router was near the end of its life. In my case replacing the router solved the issue.